# how to get string after specific char, and then get only string after another char?

Tags: regex

i have the following string:

p=1A Testing$A123

I need to a regex to get only the "A123", consider the following:

1. The "A" can be any character between a-z (maybe more than single character)
2. there is only 1 $ sign after the "p="
3. There can be other "$" signs before the "p=".

any ideas?

Comment: Which language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex expression should be something like: `p=.*\$(\w+[0-9]*)`

```
p=          matches the p=
.*          matches any character greedily
\$          matches the $
(\w+[0-9]*) matches a capture group: \w+ (a group of least one characters) followed by [0-9]* (a group of numbers (optional))
```

Change the [0-9]* to [0-9]+ if there should be at least one digit following the characters after the $.

Answer (score 0):

Using capturing group:

Javascript:

```
'a=3$bcc,p=1A Testing$A123'.match(/p=.*\$(\w+)/)[1]
// => "A123"
```

Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'p=.*\$(\w+)', r'a=3$bcc,p=1A Testing$A123').group(1)
'A123'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javasript:

```
var s = 'p=1A Testing$A123';
var m = s.match(/p=[^$]*$(.*)$/);
// ["p=1A Testing$A123", "A123"]
// use m[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/^\p=[^$]*\$[A-Z]\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

`.*?p=[^$]*\$([a-z].*)$`

Change the capturing group `([a-z].*)` with a pattern you want to use to match the end of the input.

For instance,

- `([a-z]\d*)` : beginning by [a-Z] followed by a sequence of decimals 0 or more times.
- `([a-z]\d{3})` : beginning by [a-Z] followed by a sequence of decimals exactly 3 times.
- ...